# Flex: Problem with CollectionEvent on ArrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex, arraycollection

got a reference to an arrayCollection and add event listener like this:

```
collection.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, onCollectionChange);
```

that´s fine. Now some other component does have the same reference and is adding items to and removing items from that collection. Each time the handler is called:

```
private function onProjectPersonsChange(event:Event):void
{
  if (event.kind == CollectionEventKind.ADD)
  {
   //do something

  }
  else if (event.kind == CollectionEventKind.REMOVE)
  {
   //do something

            //here is the problem: event.items.length = 0

  }
  else
  {
   trace('CollectionEvent: kind not handled!');
  }
}
```

Does somebody know why the removed item is not in 'items'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a bug. Try using a newer SDK version, or check https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/